# Create DOM elements using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, dom, rss

Hi I am trying to retrieve RSS feed using PHP and javascript.

I can get RSS feeds by using PHP but I want to create DOM elements for RSS feed using javascript. I am not sure how to complete this. Could anyone share some tips? Thanks a lot.

```
PHP

    function parse_rss_feed($url){
        $contents= file_get_contents($url);
        $xmlStr= simplexml_load_string($contents);
        return $xmlStr;
    }

    function get_rss_feed($xmlStr){

         echo '<ul>';

          foreach ($xmlStr->item as $node):

              //I want to transfer my RSS value to my javascript....

                $title=$node->title;
                $author=$node->creator;

                $desc=$node->description; 

           endforeach;

            echo '</ul>';

      }
```

html

```
 <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slideshow.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <?php
     include 'getFeed.php';
     parse_rss_feed('http://myRSSFeed')
     get_rss_feed($xmlStr)
   ?>
</body>
```

slideshow.js

```
var rss=document.createElement('artical');

//How do I get the value from my php...
rss.innerHtml=.......???
```

Comment: something like: `document.createElement('ul');`

Comment: @Jerry: You're missing a second single quote in the parameter to `document.createElement`.

Comment: @C0deH4cker Thanks for the help. little typo there.

Comment: Yup. That's not the problem, but just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: @CwdeH4cker would you be able to help me for my problem? Please see my updated question. TY.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't be easier, [`createElement()`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document/createElement).

```
var el = document.createElement('div')
```

**Edit:**

To mix  JavaScript with PHP just escape it as you'd usually do but I suggest if you're doing something serious to learn about [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

```
?>
<script>
  var foo = <?php echo 'baz' ?>
</script>
<?php
```

Comment: I understand I can use createElement to create DOM but not sure how to integrate my php code with JS. How can I transfer $node->description value under JS. +1 though.

Comment: unless `baz` is another js variable, you've just introduced a syntax error and killed all further JS. always echo stuff out with `json_encode()` to ensure you're generating syntactically valid JS values.

Comment: @elclanrs Thanks again, I still have trouble doing this, I also update my question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, yeah you're right, it was the most minimal comprehensive example I could think of.

Comment: Just don't forget to add the element to the page.

Comment: @elclanrs I am still having trouble. Please see my updated question. Thanks a lot.